# How to create a type with unique characters

Tags: typescript

How to create a type with unique characters separated by a `-`?

```
type Char = 'a' | 'b' | 'c';

type UniqueChars =
  `${Char}-${Char}-${Char}`;
```

But with no repeating chars...

Comment: Does my answer work for you?

Comment: @captain-yossarian Yeah, sorry, forgot to accept the answer. Thank you!

Comment: No worries Roberto! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compute a permutation of all allowed pairs:

```js
type Char = 'a' | 'b' | 'c';

type HandleEmpty<R extends string, S extends string> = R extends '' ? S : `${R}-${S}`

type Values<T> = T[keyof T]

type Permutation<U extends string, R extends string = ''> = {
    [S in U]: Exclude<U, S> extends never ? `${R}-${S}` : Permutation<Exclude<U, S>, HandleEmpty<R, S>>;
}[U];

// "a-b-c" | "a-c-b" | "b-a-c" | "b-c-a" | "c-a-b" | "c-b-a"
type UniqueChars = Values<{
    [Prop in Permutation<Char>]: Prop
}>
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKALgngDgpgBAYQBYEMBOcC8cDkKdwA%20uARgcTgMY4DcookscAEigHYAmANjAKIC2USAB4ASnBgAPMDE4BnOHLBoAlmwDmAGjgBlCdNkcFS1RoB8WOOKkz5uAgH5dcAFxwABgBIA3qIC%20ALQ%20On7u9ODQ8ABqKFwArjBywgAqFtjJANoA1jAQAPYAZnDJALrhjPAACjBo-HFgKGAqeWzCAKr6tkaKympaVp2Gxr0aljg4aXDeoHCzcBl6anBtJW68kpTxHDDt2joWNkNwbDAAbjVwTl6%20gcGhrnDVtfWNza3rm3Hbu7pm2qycHgCIQQMR7MxmOggPwZFZQ0AAegRcAARCgAiQApQUURUejKBiccQUZj8UTUZiCShySiqYTcbSMQFqQxIss2CoAI4JZDoBTYGLxRLCaYgObzSpoPJQOBLJ51BpNFrCXloMyrR5SqCgPxmcJAA)